# Kentico: Exclude specific pages from Breadcrumbs

Tags: asp.net, .net, content-management-system, breadcrumbs, kentico

Just a simple question on Kentico: Is it possible to exclude some pages from rendering the CMS breadcrumbs?

Specifically, our users want the homepage not to render any breadcrumbs so I'm trying to exclude that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kinda tricky. But if you ensure that breadcrumb control has no data you can hide it via 'Hide if no record found' settings.

Set WHERE condition of the Breadcrumb web part to the following macro:

```
{% if(CurrentDocument.NodeAliasPath == "/Homepage"){"1=0"}else{"1=1"} #%}
```

Obviously, you have to use node alias path of your homepage.

Set 'Hide if no record found' to `true`.

Comment: That did the trick! Appreciate the speedy reply. I did try to use the WHERE clause earlier, but I had no idea about the syntax, let alone that it is a macro.